# Can't target one specific element using the CSS selector within BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scoop out the string `834 - 1540 SqFt` on this [website](https://www.livabl.com/atlanta-ga/j5). While doing that, I could notice that using `.content-text:-soup-contains('SqFt')`, the selector can locate both the `834 - 1540 SqFt` and `$505 per SqFt` portions since both strings contain the keyword `SqFt`.

What should be the selector to target only the string "834 - 1540 SqFt"?

Btw, it is not necessary that the fields in there will always appear in the same order, so only relying on `.select_one()` when the selector is targeting two elements is not the ideal choice.

```
import urllib3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

link = 'https://www.livabl.com/atlanta-ga/j5'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(link,verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    try:
        sq_ft = soup.select(".overview-development-details .content-text:-soup-contains('SqFt')")
    except AttributeError: sq_ft = ""
    print(sq_ft)
```

Current output:

```
[<div class="content-text">
<span>834 - 1540 SqFt</span>
</div>, <div class="content-text">
<span>$505 per SqFt</span>
</div>]
```

Expected output:

```
[<div class="content-text">
<span>834 - 1540 SqFt</span>
</div>]
```

Comment: Impossible.  You can't use CSS to compare based on content.  Even if you grab all of the `<div>`s, how will you decide which one you want?  Both of them contain "SqFt".

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to solve, just use `select_one` instead of `select`. I did it here, and the result was what you would like.

```
import urllib3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

link = 'https://www.livabl.com/atlanta-ga/j5'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(link,verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    try:
        sq_ft = soup.select_one(".overview-development-details .content-text:-soup-contains('SqFt')")
    except AttributeError: sq_ft = ""
    print(sq_ft)
```

Note that only the line **sq_ft = soup.select_one(".overview-development-details .content-text:-soup-contains('SqFt')")** has changed

Answer (score 0):

You can regex to match the text patterns.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

link = 'https://www.livabl.com/atlanta-ga/j5'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(link,verify=False).text,"lxml")
    sq_ft = soup.find('span', string=re.compile('^\d+.*SqFt$')) if soup.find('span', string=re.compile('^\d+.*SqFt$')) else ''
    print(sq_ft)
```

In this code, I am looking for any span tag with text starting with a number, and ending with SqFt, which results in your expected element.

Output:

```
<span>834 - 1540 SqFt</span>
```